# Swift 5.0 Xcode outputs "Program ended with exit code: 0" when printing file path

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to access a JSON formatted .txt file(usersAPI). I have my project on Xcode set up as a command-line project(not sure if this matters). I've gotten the txt file in my local files, but the path never outputs on the console other than "Program ended with exit code: 0".

```
import Foundation

func viewDidLoad() {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "usersAPI", ofType: "txt") else {return}
    
    print(path)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems going on:

1. In a command line tool, you won't use `viewDidLoad`, because there's no view to load. So, your program immediately exits, because there's nothing to run -- just a function that never gets called. If you wanted to run the function that you wrote, you'd have to explicitly call `viewDidLoad()` at the top level of your app.
2. Command line tools don't have Bundles like other Mac/iOS apps do, so your `Bundle.main.path(...)` code won't return anything. You can find other resources on SO about how to read files from your command line app, such as: [How do I read a file from the filesystem in a Swift command line app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251445/how-do-i-read-a-file-from-the-filesystem-in-a-swift-command-line-app/54251985)